# How to insert data from google analytic dynamically in data.addRows()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-visualization

I am using data analytics and trying to use google charts with it.

I try to pass the response from the google analytics to generate google charts.

I successfully implement the data.addColumn, but data.addRow give error "Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array "

```
 function drawCharts(response)
 {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  header = response.columnHeaders[0];
  data.addColumn('string', header.name);
  for (var i = 0, header; header = response.columnHeaders[i]; i++){

        data.addColumn('number', header.name);
      }
var result = '';
   for(var i=0; i<response.rows.length; i++) {
      result += '["'+response.rows[i]+'"],';
    }
      result = result.substring(0, result.length - 1);
        alert(result); //image attached
        data.addRows(result);

         var options = {'title':response.profileInfo.profileName,
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

      }
```

Kindly, help....! I have been trying for hours...!!

alert result gives me something like this;
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a string out of the rows?  The #addRows method takes an array of arrays.

What happens if you just call `data.addRows(response.rows);`?

Also, your method of adding the columns needs to be tweaked a bit, as you are adding the first column twice.  Start the `for` loop at `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`, as you are already pulling result.columnHeaders[0] into a column.

```
header = response.columnHeaders[0];
data.addColumn('string', header.name);
for (var i = 1, header; header = response.columnHeaders[i]; i++){
    data.addColumn('number', header.name);
}
```

Comment: @asagallant using `data.addRows(response.rows);` gives this error _Error: Type mismatch. Value 2013 does not match type number in column index 1_

Comment: What are the contents of response.rows?

Comment: Don't use an alert, that only gives a string representation of `response.rows`.  I want to know if it is an array or a string.  Insert the line `console.dir(response.rows);` and open the page in Chrome or Firefox, and post the output in the developer's console.

Comment: It gives me `array[15]`.

Comment: The console should allow you to expand the array to see its contents, I need to see what's inside each row.